# How can I list ous (organizational units) below a specified ou in Active Directory C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, enumeration

As I'm not very experienced in terms of retrieving information from the Active Directory I hope to get some pointers into the right direction.

I'd like to list all ous (organizational units) below a specified ou, but unfortunately I don't know how to get things working.

Let's say that the structure in our AD is as follows

```
SomeStartingPoint
|-MySpecifiedOuName
  |-SubOuName1
    |-SubOuName2
```

What I've got so far is

```
DirectoryEntry rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry( "LDAP://RootDSE" );
string defaultNamingContext = rootDSE.Proeprties[ "defaultNamingContext" ].Value.ToString();
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry( "LDAP://" + defaultNamingContext );
DirectorySearcher ouSearch = 
    new DirectorySearcher( entry.Path ) { Filter = "(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)", SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree };
 
ouSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add( "name" );
ouSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add( "adspath" );
SearchResultCollection allOUs = ouSearch.FindAll();
```

Now I can loop over the `allOUs` and access `.Properties[ "name" ][ 0 ]` and `.Properties[ "adspath" ][ 0 ]` to list the values for all OUs.

Now when I try to use a different filter as in `Filter = (&(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)(ou=MySpecifiedOuName))`, I do get the single entry corresponding to exactly `MySpecifiedOuName`, but not the underlying OUs below, even though they contain `MySpecifiedOuName` within their path. This is probably down to the fact that in my example I query the wrong thing (the OU directly), but I don't know any other way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Rather than loading `adsPath` which is an ADSI abstraction, grab `distinguishedName` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do what you want is in a recursive fashion. `ou` is the RDN attribute for the OU (much like `CN` is for users). Thus doing a search for `ou=foo` will only get you OUs with their `OU` attribute set to foo.

In order to walk the chain, you're going to need to do a search for all the OUs at the current level (use a `OneLevel` search instead of `SubTree`), and then recurse through there. This is not at all efficient, though, since you're going to be issuing numerous queries to AD.

Instead, you could do what you're doing and then build your hierarchy by sorting based on DN/depth. This is more complex but it will be more efficient from a resource access point of view.

Comment: Thanks Brian, this is the way to do it and it worked for me as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Just try with this filter :

```
"(objectCategory=CN=Organizational-Unit,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=dom,DC=fr)"
```

Adapted to your domain with `configurationNamingContext` from the RootDSE for `CN=Configuration,DC=dom,DC=fr`

This may be explained by the fact that objectCategory is a distinguich name, I know that Microsoft tools are making the translation but it seems not to work for you here.

-----Edited-----

As @Desmond insist on the fact `"(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)"` I just test it an it works. `"(objectCategory=CN=Organizational-Unit,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=dom,DC=fr)"` also works.

```
DirectoryEntry deBase = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://WM2008R2ENT:389/dc=dom,dc=fr", "jpb", "Pwd");

/* Directory Search
 */
DirectorySearcher dsLookForOUs = new DirectorySearcher(deBase);
dsLookForOUs.Filter = "(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)";
dsLookForOUs.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
dsLookForOUs.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
dsLookForOUs.PropertiesToLoad.Add("ou");

SearchResultCollection srcOUs = dsLookForOUs.FindAll();

foreach (SearchResult srOU in srcOUs)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0}", srOU.Path);
}
```

Comment: No need to use the whole DN - (objectCategory=organizationalUnit) is sufficient

Comment: You are right, but as I never know if it's solved on client part or in server part, and objectCategory is a DN.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and sorry for not getting back to you earlier. But isn't the example above basically the same as my code? I do get the same result if I don't use the amended filter (i.e. when I only use objectCategory=organizationalUnit), so in that case I can go on and filter the returned collection based on the length of the path or similar nasty approaches. Please let me know whether I've missed something in your suggestion otherwise.

Comment: I just think, that I don't really understand your question. I beleive that you were not receiving the list of OUs. In fact you receive the list of OUs, but you want to create the tree. In this case you have to write a recursive method that search OU with base scope and for each OU recall itself till there is no OU.

Comment: My question was whether I could only those OUs that are below a certain specified OU. As it seems, there is not really a filter / query directly for that and I used a recursive approach that seems to work for me now. My misunderstanding of the AD was the hope for someone to come up with a single query that would deliver "all OUs below OU XY (which in itself might be a random OU somewhere within the tree, not necessarily the root). Anyway, thanks for your help, I will mark Brian's answer as correct as that's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You most likley are only missing the `subtree` option:

```
ouSearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is already being set in the initialisation of the constructor (see in my code above) and didn't help.

Comment: Indeed. I've overlooked it since I haven't scrolled to the right of your code far enough.